# lint-staged fails with "npm could not be found. Try `npm install npm`."

Tags: javascript, npm, pre-commit-hook, husky, lint-staged

I have `lint-staged` installed in a multi-package repository.

The structure is:

```
|-- package.json
|-- package-one
   |-- package.json
   |-- javascript
|-- package-two
   |-- package.json
   |-- javascript
```

**I have the same setup in a different repo on the same machine and the below works with no errors.**

I am using lint-staged to run eslint on pre-commit. Each sub-package has a `lint` npm script in it.

In the other repository I call `lint-staged` on each package without error, however, in this repo when running against a stage file it:

- correctly identifies the staged file
- produces the error `npm could not be found. Try npm install npm.`
- if I change the npm script out to simply be `"git add"` then the error is `git could not be found. Try npm install git.`

Running `which npm` produces the same results in the working and non-working repos.

Running `npm install` or any other npm command works when ran directly, just not when ran through `lint-staged`.

I am at a loss as to what may be causing this?

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "husky": "^2.4.1",
        "lint-staged": "^8.2.1",
    },
    "lint-staged": {
        "packages/package-name/**/*.{js,jsx}": [
            "npm run --silent lint --prefix packages/package-one"
        ]
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `npm` installed globally?

Comment: Yes, for several months. I use `nvm` to manage it across repos. In both the repo that works and the one that does not `which npm` results in:
`/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v8.16.0/bin/npm`